# How to get an Domain name to resolve to a EC2 without changing it to an IP address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, domain-name, amazon-elb

I have an EC2 instance running wordpress and mysql and set up a Load Balancer (Even thou I only have one server) and route 53 to direct traffic.

My domain (ie. example.com) is using the name servers from route 53 to route traffic to the application load balancer that has my EC2 instance listed as a target group. This issues i am having is when this happens in the URL in by browser it changes to example.com to the public IP address of the server which simple doesn't look good.

AWS seem have gone under a few changes since I last did this however I cannot figure out where my mistake is? The site loads, the domain name resolves to the server, but it changes it to an IP address rather than leaving it as example.com

Update: 
Since a lot are bringing up ALB, i do have one and R53 is using it. Its not anything special.

- I gave it a name
- Select two availability zones
- Security group is Wide open (For testing sake)
- Selected a Target group includes the single EC2 instance

Comment: Is your R53 record set correctly set to point to dns of your ALB, not the IP address of the instance?

Comment: I have it pointing to the Alias for the LB and not the static IP.

Comment: if you running ec2 instances behind ALB, they shouldn't have a public ip address

Comment: That is where my confusion comes in. I seem to recall having an issues like this is the past, but cannot remember the cause. I just started over it the next time though it was fine. The only thing I can recall I did differently was had a second server for the ALB. So instead of a single EC2 i had two of them. But not sure what else I did as I don't think that was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In Route 53 create an A record, set it as an Alias record by ticking yes for Alias then select your ALB

Comment: Run dig against it: https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/. Validate it is resolving.

Comment: For the sake of trying I recreated the ALB and set R53 to use that. Using Record A just as before. Still change it from example.com to the public IP of the EC2 instance.

Comment: @monkugo-devops I tried what you suggested it did resolve. Thou It's resolving to a second IP address as well. That IP address is also working to get to the site too. I may also be worth point out that I am using an Elastic IP but I am not sure what this means if anything

Comment: Yep that's because load balancers have multiple public IPs (one per AZ). This means its not a DNS issue but likely to be an application issue which is doing the redirect

Comment: @monkugo-devops If it is the application what can I look for or where might I start? I have Wordpress and a DB running in a container.

Comment: I believe Wordpress has a base domain https://wpengine.co.uk/resources/change-domains-wordpress/

Comment: That was it, it would have taken me weeks to figure that out (Pretty new to WordPress) Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

It feels like the `wp_options` database table does not point to the DNS record configured in Route53. You can either update columns `wp_options.site_url` and `wp_options.home` with the correct domain or set it in `wp-config.php`